# google visualization API query ReferenceError: "google" is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

how come when I paste this code into my script:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language

and run it, it gives me this error:

> ReferenceError: "google" is not defined.

?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Google Visualization API" needs to be loaded first: [follow the quick start](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start).

> You can copy the snippet below to a file on your computer and open it in your browser to display the pie chart shown above:

Snippet of code from link:

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {
    // !!! Use Google Visualization API here !!!
  }
</script>
```

Note that the Google Visualization API is *only* available after `drawChart` is called.

Comment: thanks for response pst, but i still don't understand. maybe i should rephrase the question. the question is "how do i make the code there work? what do i have to paste infront of it?" https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language

Comment: @jason_cant_code I've explained the end-solution above; the particular reason for the error is that the Google AJAX API is not being loaded correctly and a `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">` or a similar line is omitted. (This is where the `google` global variable is defined.)

Comment: I've pasted the code into my script and get a "Missing ; before statement. (line 3)". Sorry, I'm a beginner. Thanks for the hand holding.

Comment: I can only find examples of using Google Spreadsheets as Visualization *data-sources*, but I cannot find information on adding a Visualization to a Google Spreadsheet; do you have a reference/tutorial for this task?

Comment: I'm trying to use Google script to run some queries in my spreadsheets https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Order_By